# Using JSON.Net to Serialize and Deserialize Property that is a List of Interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have read several Posts here on SO that are similar but most of them are trying to do something more difficult that what I am trying to accomplish.  The remaining posts did not seem to work for me.

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Zone
{
   public Zone() { Areas = new List<IZoneArea>(); }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<IZoneArea> Areas { get; set; }
}

public class ZoneArea
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

All I want to do, is take a populated collection of Zones e.g. List zones, and successfully Serialize them AND DeSerialize them using JsonConvert and the Serialize / Deserialize Object methods.  I can never seem to make it work.

Here is what I have tried so far:
1.  Added an attribute above the Areas Property in the Zone Class as Follows `[JsonConverter(typeof(ZoneAreaConverter))]`

Then wrote and tried a few different ZoneArea Converters as follows:

```
// This method is the same in all the variations
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{
    return objectType == typeof(IZoneArea);
}

// The following is only one of the variations of the ReadJson method I tried
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var data = JObject.Load(reader);
        var area = new ZoneArea();
        serializer.Populate(data.CreateReader(), area);

        return area;
    }

public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
```

2. After several variations I took a different recommended approach also here from SO and removed the attribute from the Zone class and instead created a CustomCreationConverter as follows:

   ```
    public class ZoneAreaConverter : CustomCreationConverter<IZoneArea>
    {
         public override IZoneArea Create(Type objectType)
         {
             return new ZoneArea();
         }
    }
   ```

and tried to to deserialize as so:

```
  var zones = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Zone>>(cache.Cache.ToString(), new ZoneAreaConverter());
```

I keep feeling like I'm very close but missing something.

Comment: It seems to me that you're doing more than you need to. Is there a reason you're writing a custom converter? I've posted an answer, just using the standard JsonConvert methods, that seems like they should work fine in your case.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem -- your `CustomCreationConverter<IZoneArea>` works just fine.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/O3xPfx.  Can you edit your question to include a [complete example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O3xPfx) that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Why are you passing in a converter? And what is cache? Have you tried simply: `return serializer.Deserialize<List<ZoneArea>>(reader);` inside of your ReadJson method?

Comment: @dbc How did I miss dotnetfiddle.net!  This is awesome!  You were in fact right.  I took everything and put it into its own solution and it worked beautifully.  Is the Formatting.Indented important to the process or is it just making it more readable?

Comment: @jrandomuser - Formatting.Indented is just to make it look pretty.